# load excel template file and write data to cell?

Tags: c#

I have a excel template file (C:\Report\Template\abc.xls).
I need to write a C# console application to do following,

1. copy the abc.xls file from Template folder and save the same template with different name and different folder "Data" ((C:\Report\Data\new_abc.xls)
2. load the "new_abc.xls" file into memory and write data (comes from database) to it's specific cell (for example i want to write in cell H17)

Please let me suggest or give me link or code to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Copying files is easily done with [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx).  Simply pass in the source path from which to copy and the destination path to copy to as strings.
2. Take a look at the [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) classes for manipulating Excel workbooks.  Here's a [good code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get you started.  Also [this is another overview](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel).

Comment: I've given you some code samples if you click on the links (there are four links in my post).  For example, if you click into the first method on `File.Copy` documentation page, there are code samples on how to use it.  The MSDN documentation is generally pretty good at providing sample code.  Note, however, SO is not the place to get your code written for you.  We'll answer specific questions once you've dug in and have some trouble.